# Creating tableview cell content programmatically

Tags: swift

I want to create UItableViewCell ui programmatically based on API response.

I'm using a API that output a set of articles, but the content of these articles could be deferent, for example some articles may not have a description, or some of them may not have a image. I want to create Tableview cells programmatically based on these data.

I have tried setting constraints in viewDidLoad method of the cell but It does not work.

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: you can use stack view and hide the views that doesn't get data

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how different the articles are from each other, you could either choose to design multiple different kinds of cells for your table view and choose which cell to use for a given row based on the data you have, or you could design a single cell that uses a stack view to hide the labels that you don't have data for. When you set a view inside a stack view to `isHidden = true` then the stack view will resize its subviews as if the hidden view does not exist.